# Internet Explorer 10 Does Not Sent Ajax Post Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post, internet-explorer-10

Ok, I researched this for several hours and I'm still stumped.

Internet explorer ten will submit ajax requests using jquery, but it will not include the post data.

Here is the code:

```
var ajaxData = "FirstName="+encodeURIComponent($('#FirstName').val()); //get the data from the account form
                ajaxData += "&LastName="+encodeURIComponent($('#LastName').val()); 
                ajaxData += "&EmailAddress="+encodeURIComponent($('#EmailAddress').val());
                ajaxData += "&CAT_Custom_246311="+encodeURIComponent(listData);

                var config = {
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/FormProcessv2.aspx?WebFormID=44714&OID={module_oid}&OTYPE={module_otype}&EID={module_eid}&CID={module_cid}&JSON=1",
                    dataType: "json", // text"json",
                    processData: false,
                    data: ajaxData,
                    timeout: 70000,
                    cache: false,

                };

                $.ajax(config)
                .done(function(data, event) {
                    if(data.FormProcessV2Response.success == true){ //success field is in BC response
                        alert("The list was submitted sucessfully.");
                        console.log(XHR);
                    } else{
                        alert("An error occurred and the list was not submitted.");
                    }
                })
                .fail(function(msg,event) {
                    alert("An error occurred and the list was not submitted.");
                });
```

Every other browser (safari, opera, chrome, firefox, IE9) will allow this to work, but the code fails in IE 10. Looking at it using fiddler shows that the headers are almost the same between the other browsers and IE 10, but IE 10's request headers have a Content length value of 0, and there is no body text.

In reference to some of the other problems that people have been having, no, I do not have any download manager style plugins. All plugins are default. Here is a photo of the plugins I have for the record.

[image: Plugins]

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST",config.url,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(config.data);
}
```

This is the dummy text from w3schools for a raw request, with my own data.

Here is an example of the value for the data that is given by internet Explorer itself (using dev tools)

```
FirstName=Joe&LastName=Spacely&EmailAddress=tester%40test.com&CAT_Custom_246311=test%3Dtest
```

I am using Internet Explorer 10.0.9200.16519 on Windows 8 x64 w/Media Pack.

Does Internet Explorer just not support it at all?

Any help would be appreciated. Oh, and please refrain from telling me about how bad IE is. We all know it, but we web developers still have to deal with it.

Comment: Do you have jQuery included correctly in your page?

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) is hardly a good source for examples. I wouldn't even call it a BAD source.

Comment: Why are you setting `processData` to `false`? It looks like you're building a query string of the data there.

Comment: does it have something to do with your URL already having `$_POST` data on there? perhaps if you include that information in your variable and just have static URL ull have more success. and btw, you might consider using `{key:value}` pairs, since building a query string is far more difficult to maintain.

Comment: @Mooseman ... what does that have to do with this question?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers, all.
Mooseman yes jquery is included correctly. It works in all the other browsers.

Marc B, Same thing using MSDN...and the actual XMLHttpRequest specs (but we know how well IE follows those!)

@LifeInTheGrey, good question. I will look at that and see. I'll get back with you all.

Comment: Ok, @LifeInTheGrey has the correct answer but it doesn't solve my problem. By shifting the information from the url Query string into the  post body, internet explorer did submit the information as I observed using fiddler. However, Adobe Business Catalyst, the backend that I am working on, cannot process the info if said fields are in the body. Lame BC. Anyway, thanks. The workaround for BC users that I just found is that ajax works in IE 9, so just add the following meta tag to the page and it will work.

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">

Thanks again, all.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey, I will accept your proposal as the answer to this general problem if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as requested:

Does it have something to do with your URL already having $_POST data on there? Perhaps if you include that information in your variable and just have static URL ull have more success.

BTW, you might consider using {key:value} pairs, since building a query string is far more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Again thanks for noting the key val idea. I usually do that, but in this case, I used a pure string for clarity. I would recommend using objects as well to anyone reading this.

Comment: @VipanKumar - can u be more descriptive? because i use jQuery AJAX with proper `{key:value}` pairs all the time, and it definitely works on IE11.

Answer (score 2):

I have had problems with IE and form data before.  I found it best to make sure that my input fields are wrapped with a form tag with an id.  Then, when you post the data, use the jQuery [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to build the post data string for you.

So, your config would look something like this:

```
var config = {
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "/FormProcessv2.aspx", //truncated for simplicity
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    data: $('#formName').serialize(),
    timeout: 70000,
    cache: false
};
```

Also, just in case I'll mention to make sure if you're binding this ajax post to a form submit or button click, that you prevent the default form submit action using [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: Thanks, but this is not relevant to the topic. In the case of the topic, the information does not originate from a form.